# Javascript add shipping cost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a customer chooses a shipping method, I want the cost to appear in the checkout. The problem that I'm having is that the cost for the shipping doesn't appear in the checkout.

Here is my `javascript` code:

```
var shopcart = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
  outputCart();

  $(".productItem").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var itemInfo = $(this.dataset)[0];
    itemInfo.qty = 1;
    var itemInCart = false;

    $.each(shopcart, function (index, value) {
      //console.log(index + '  ' + value.id);
      if(value.id == itemInfo.id) {
        value.qty = parseInt(value.qty) + parseInt(itemInfo.qty);
        itemInCart = true;
      }
    })

    if(!itemInCart) {
      shopcart.push(itemInfo);
    }

    sessionStorage["sc"] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
    outputCart();
  })

  function outputCart() {
    if(sessionStorage["sc"] != null) {
      shopcart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["sc"].toString());
      //console.log(sessionStorage["sc"]);
      $('#checkoutdiv').show();
    }
    var vat25 = 0.20;
    var holderHTML = '';
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 899;
    var shippingLimit = 899;
    var shippingCost = 0 + ' kr';
    var itemCount = 0;

    $(".shippingBestTransport").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      shippingCost = 89;
    })

    $.each(shopcart, function (index, value) {
      //console.log(value);
      var stotal = value.qty * value.price;
      subtotal += stotal;
      itemCount += parseInt(value.qty);
    })

    var totalShippingLimit = (shippingLimit - subtotal);
    if(totalShippingLimit < 0) {
      totalShippingLimit = 0;
    }

    if(itemCount != 1) {
      Countending = ' Varor';
    } else {
      Countending = ' Vara';
    }

    $('.subtotal').html(formatTotal(subtotal));
    $('.total').html(formatTotal(total));
    $('.vat').html(formatVAT(total*vat25));
    $('.shippingCost').html(shippingCost);
    $('.shippingLimit').html(formatFreight(totalShippingLimit));
    $('.items').html(itemCount + Countending);
  }

  function formatTotal(n) {
    return (n/1).toFixed(2) + ' kr';
  }

  function formatVAT(n) {
    return (n/1).toFixed(2) + ' kr';
  }

  function formatFreight(n) {
    return (n).toFixed(0) + ' kr';
  }

})
```

And my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="a-black shippingBestTransport" data-name="Best Transport" data-price="89" data-id="1">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="box">
                  <h4>Best Transport (Nästa dag)</h4>
                  <p>Beställ innan klockan 13:00 för att få leverans redan nästa dag när du väljer Best Transport.</p>
                  <div class="box-footer text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="inputGroup">
                        <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><b>89 kr</b></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
```

So when a user press "Best Transport", the cost of 89 should appear in the checkout but now it doesn't.

```
$(".shippingBestTransport").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); shippingCost = 89; })
```

That part of the code should react when a user presses a button with the class `"shippingBestTransport".` And i does so far. The result should be displayed in a class like this:

```
$('.shippingCost').html(shippingCost);
```

Here is the code that should output all the variables to the checkout page:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Subtotal:</td>
              <td><span class="subtotal"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Fraktkostnad:</td>
              <td><span class="shippingCost"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Totalt:</td>
              <td><span class="total"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><em>Varav moms:</em></td>
              <td><span class="vat"></span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

But when that part of the code should return the actuall shipping-cost so that it is displayed in the checkout it doesn't do that. Nothing is displayed and i have no errors.

Comment: *"...but now it doesn't"* . So what happens instead? Any errors? What part of the code should be expected to do what you want? Take a few minutes to help us help you by reading [ask] then edit the question with more details

Comment: This part of the javascript-code:

 $(".shippingBestTransport").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      shippingCost = 89;
    })

That part of the code should react when a user presses a button with the class "shippingBestTransport". And i does so far.

The result should be displayed in a class like this:
$('.shippingCost').html(shippingCost);

But when that part of the code should return the actuall shipping-cost so that it is displayed in the checkout it doesn't do that. Nothing is displayed and i have no errors.

Comment: Ok...note those details should be edited into the question itself

Comment: Sorry for that, i have done that now. :)

Comment: No problems. Just trying to help you get used to how things work and allow others who read this to understand better

Comment: where's the element with the class 'shippingCost'?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".shippingBestTransport").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  shippingCost = 89;
})
```

This function updates the value of a variable, but nothing is done to display anything. You must now update the DOM itself, for instance:

```
$(".shippingBestTransport").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  shippingCost = 89;
  $('.shippingCost').html(shippingCost);
})
```

Another issue is that I don't see any element with class `shippingCost` in your html, did you forget to add that class?

Comment: Sorry for that, i have now added the HTML that should output the data from the javascript to my checkout page.

I will try your solution and get back to you with the result.